# How to prove $(0,1) \sim \left\{0,1 \right\}^{\mathbb{N}} $?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

How to prove $(0,1) \sim \left\{0,1 \right\}^{\mathbb{N}} $?

I know that I need to use binary expansion of $a \in (0,1)$, but I am not sure how to formally write the proof.

Comment: shouldn't that be $[0,1]$?

Comment: @user300: Why? Do they have different cardinalities?

Comment: Also, for the people who are going to post the "binary expansion" argument, there are two deleted answers that were posted and voluntarily deleted moments later when the answerers realized that the argument is wrong. We don't need a third deleted answer: the binary expansion is neither unique (so it is not an injection or a well-defined function), nor it is surjective since $0$ and $1$ (which correspond to the constant $0$ and constant $1$ sequences) are not in the interval (and also because of the uniqueness issue).

Comment: i think there is some subset relation kind of thing @Asaf Karagila .. but i'm not sure!

Comment: @user300: If you agree that $[0,1]$ and $[\frac12,\frac13]$ have the same cardinality, then by the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ have the same cardinality; you can also come up with explicit bijections, but this is yet another question that was asked ad nauseum on this site.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila: did you just say "binary expansion is not unique" ! OMG! i didn't know that

Comment: @user300: It is mostly unique, but there are infinitely many counterexamples.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila: i tried to think of some example in this case! but i couldn't! why don't you just give one example? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by showing that there are two injections $ f : (0,1) \to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} $ and $ g : \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to (0,1)$ then use Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder.

$ f(x) = n \mapsto \lfloor x2^n\rfloor \mod 2 $

$ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n)2^{-2n}$